# How does IP traceback works?

Tags: ddos, ip-spoofing

> In part prompted by the difficulties in determining the true origins
>   of DDOS attacks featuring spoofed IP addresses, researchers have
>   attempted to develop the concept of IP traceback: determining the
>   actual origin of a packet on the Internet, without relying on the IP
>   source field contained in that potentially falsified packet. Early IP
>   traceback techniques relied on logging each packet forwarded by each
>   router.

I know that IP traceback helps trace the real user that send a request by spoofing an IP address. But what information does the router logs?

Comment: The quote tells you what is recorded: the packet. I'm not sure what you are asking. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

There is no singular IP Traceback implementation, although researchers have proposed many solutions in the past.

If you look at the [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_traceback) article under the "Router based approach" section, you will find a few proposed methods of fingerprinting a packet.

Here's an [article](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/about/press/internet-protocol-journal/back-issues/table-contents-38/104-ip-spoofing.html) from CISCO that touches on techniques routers can perform to prevent IP spoofing.

I'm not aware of any router that has a turnkey solution that performs IP Traceback outside of your own network though. There isn't a standard protocol to request an IP Traceback.